# How to delete a post from a Google Group?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-groups-api

How can I delete a post from a Google Group using Google Apps Scripts?

How can I get the list of topics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would imagine that because Google Groups underlying technology is email you will not be able to delete a post as it has been sent already.
You will probably have to use Gmail Services to accomplish the list of topics task. 
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_gmail

Comment: This is a great idea. The group is a mail box and seek Him in it! I will try and answer.

Comment: There is no way to programatically access messages archived in a Google Group. Nor can you programatically delete messages in a Google Group.