# Is there a way to automatically delete emails from a Google Workspace Google Groups?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-groups

I was wondering if there is a way to automatically (or on a trigger) delete emails from a Google Group.

I use a Collaborative Inbox Group for archiving automated emails.
I looked at the Google Apps Script overview for Google Groups, but I don't see anything. It only seems like you can do this from GmailApp...

I also read this thread from 2012 but nothing helpful [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017838/how-to-delete-a-post-from-a-google-group)

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*Programmatically this isn't possible.*

#### More Information:

The `GroupsApp` class of Apps Script only has [read methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/groups) available for use - there is not a way of executing any write data using the class - for example deletion of emails.

Emails are sent to everyone in the group when a post is made (as per subscription settings). If you want the Email to be deleted then as you have already pointed out, you will need to use GmailApp to delete it from the recipients' inboxes.

**In short: All mailbox manipulation must be done using the Gmail API (or GmailApp).**

#### Feature Request:

You can however let Google know that this is a feature that is important for access to their APIs, and that you would like to request they implement it.

Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) is a place for developers to report issues and make feature requests for their development services, I'd urge you to make a feature request there. The best component to file this under would be the [Admin SDK component](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191635&template=824102), with the `Feature Request` template.